# Change background color when slideToggle back?

Tags: jquery

When I click on a element to slideToggle some other elements, I also change the background color of the element that I clicked on to indicate that this is the selected. But how do I remove the background color when I click and slideToggle back the elements?

```
$(".c756:eq(0)").click(function(){
    $(".c756:eq(0)").css('background-color','yellow');
    $("#wrapper_datorpaket").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`toggle` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
$('.c756:eq(0)').toggle(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
}, function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
}).click(function () {
    $('#wrapper_datorpaket').slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would set a "highlight" class and use `toggleClass` with a switch set to the visibility of the wrapper element.

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow
}

$(".c756:eq(0)").click(function(){
    var that = this;
    $("#wrapper_datorpaket").slideToggle(function() {

        // this doesn't have to be in the callback
        // unless you want the highlight added/removed
        // on completion of the animation
        $(that).toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":visible"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I was hoping you could tell me how to edit my script so that the highlight change is instant not at the end of animation, can't figure this out. 
`$(function() {
 $('.contents').hide();
    $('body').on('click', '.product', function() {
  var that = this;
        $(this).find('.contents').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        $(that).toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":visible"));
    });
    });
});`